# Google Map Android Listeners for markers and marker clusters

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, listener, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am interested in two listeners, I do not know even if they exist...

1º: Listens when a Cluster is shown:

When you are doing zoom up in the map, you reach a height in which the cluster 
is shown, hiding the individual markers. I want a listener that detects when this happens.

**Reason**: the location of the cluster is the location of one of the markers clustered inside of it, I want the cluster to be shown in the average location of the markers inside of it.

2º: Listens when a marker is not anymore in the view:

When you click on marker (or ClusterItem), InfoWindow is shown. Then if you slide through the map until you do not see the marker anymore, the infowindow of the marker is still shown but the navigation buttons of the map disappear.

**Reason**: I find this a bit illogical, I would like to have both elements shown or hidden (infowindow and navigation buttons).

Maybe this listeners do not exist, but there are other ways of achieving this.